# Displaying a Desktop Shortcut for a device having windows ce 4.2 (VS 2003)

Tags: deployment, windows-ce

I have developed a Windows CE 4.2 Application in VS 2003. When i deploy the CAB file in the device having X86 has its processor, a short cut for the application is created in Start >> Program >> Application. But I want a short cut for the application on the 
desktop.

I modified the INF file to add a new shortcut that points to the desktop folder inside windows folder but it didn't work. Also, If i replace the default shortcut created when I build the CAB file with the location of desktop it still creates a short cut in the Programs and not on the desktop.

Does anyone has a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms938387.aspx

That should get you well on your way. Basically shortcuts in CE are just ASCII files of the format:

21#\Windows\solitare.exe

Where 21# is the number of characters in that path. Here's another link to MSDN with more info on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/embedded/aa731295.aspx

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the INF file, how did you regenrate the CAB?  You must *not* use the menu item in Studio (can't recall if '03 had that option) as it will overwrite your INF.

If you're manually generating the CAB with CABWIZ, then show us your INF file, as you likely have something wrong there.